# Typescript: Discovering and constructing types at run time?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a tricky Typescript problem that is stumping me- How can I reflect to get unknown property types so that I can set properties dynamically?

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```js
class JumpParameters { constructor(data: string) {} }
class RunParameters { constructor(data: string) {} }

// Thing is an object I want to construct dynamically from data
// that I discover at runtime.  *** NOTE: neither makething, nor the
// caller of makething are allowed to know the types in Thing at
// Compile time.  
class Thing {
    action?: {
        jump?: JumpParameters,
        run?: RunParameters,
    }
}

function makeThing(name: string, data: string)
{
    const output = new Thing();

    // *** First problem: How do I get the type of action so that  
    // I can look for the properties on the next line?
    const actionType = ???; 

    for(let property of actionType.Properties) {
        if(property.name === name) {

            // *** Second Problem: how do I discover the types of the 
            // properties on action so that I can construct them?
            const subType = ???;

            output.action[name] = new subType(data);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to express that an action can either be Jump or Run. This can be expressed with a union type:

```js
class JumpParameters { constructor(data: string) {} }
class RunParameters { constructor(data: string) {} }

interface JumpAction {
    actionType: "Jump";
    jump: JumpParameters,
}

interface RunAction {
    actionType: "Run",
    run: RunParameters
}

type Action = JumpAction | RunAction;
type ActionType = Action["actionType"];

interface Thing {
    action?: Action;
}

function makeThing(actionType: ActionType, data: string): Thing
{
    let action: Action;
    switch (actionType) {
        case "Jump":
            const jumpAction: JumpAction = {
                actionType: "Jump",
                jump: new JumpParameters(data)
            };
            action = jumpAction; 
            break;
        case "Run":
            const runAction: RunAction = {
                actionType: "Run",
                run: new RunParameters(data)
            };
            action = runAction; 
            break;
    }

    return {
        action
    };
}
```

Now, you may want to avoid the switch statement in the case that you have a lot of different action types. If you find that actions generally have the same sort of data (as they currently do) we can make things simpler:

```js
abstract class ActionParameters<T extends ActionType> {
    constructor(data: string) {}
}

class JumpParameters extends ActionParameters<"Jump"> {}
class RunParameters extends ActionParameters<"Run"> {}

const actionParametersCtors: {[k in ActionType]: { new(data: string): ActionParameters<k> }} = {
    "Jump": JumpParameters,
    "Run": RunParameters, 
}

type ActionType = "Jump" | "Run";

interface Action<T extends ActionType> {
    actionType: ActionType,
    parameters: ActionParameters<T>,
}

interface Thing<T extends ActionType> {
    action?: Action<T>;
}

function makeThing<T extends ActionType>(actionType: T, data: string): Thing<T>
{
    const action: Action<T> = {
        actionType,
        parameters: new actionParametersCtors[actionType](data)
    };

    return {
        action
    };
}
```

Note that we still need an explicit map between ActionType and the parameter constructor in this case.

Also, it's quite possible that `ActionParameters` doesn't end up requiring that generic parameter when you're implementing it, so you could get rid of it and make things even simpler.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.   I did consider this route, however there is one major twist:  my code is a library, and so it is not allowed to know what the types are in order to call makeThing<T> with the right T.    I need some sort of reflection to discover the types.

Comment: @EricJorgensen Can you elaborate? Which parts are stuck in library code and which are  user code?

Comment: I added some extra info in the original post.   The makeThing is in the library, but Thing, JumpParameters, and RunParameters are not known to the library and must be discovered at runtime.

Comment: If `Thing` is entirely unknown to the caller at compile time, you're limited to Javascript's runtime type checking. But then how are you going to construct a new instance of `Thing` if the library doesn't even know what the type of `Thing` is? You could have the user code pass in the `Thing` constructor and require it construct something like what you want I suppose. 
You'll probably want to replace `let property of actionType.Properties` with something like `for const key of Object.keys(thing.action)`.
It might be a good idea to do some reading on the difference between types and values.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.   If it helps, as a model for this, I am using the reflection feature from C#.   In C#, I can pass an unknown type and the the recipient can dynamically discover all the aspects of the type, including how to construct it.   The type can be passed explicitly or I can just ask any unknown object for it's type.   I think the disconnect for me is that I think of types as objects but they seem to be something different in Typescript.

Comment: That's right - types are completely erased at runtime, due to the fact that typescript isn't executed at all - it's simply compiled down to Javascript. This is different to something like C# where type information can be accessed at runtime (albeit with incredible runtime costs ;) )

Comment: That being said, there are a lot of reflection-like things you can do in js, owing simply to the fact that every object is a dict, which has keys you can iterate over.